# Does Akka natively support Integration Patterns?

Tags: apache-camel, akka, actor, thread-synchronization, enterprise-integration

I am new to Akka and am trying to figure out whether it has built-in support for [Enterprise Integration Patterns (EIP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns) or whether I need to delegate this type of routing/integration out to a framework like [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

In my use case, I have an actor that reads binary samples from a source (file); this actor is called the `Sampler`. The `Sampler` than passes `Sample` instances (messages) out to a field of actors called `SampleProcessors`. Each sample processor does something different to a given `Sample`. Depending on the outcome of a processor processing a `Sample`, it may need to be routed to 1+ other `SampleProcessor`, or perhaps all processing has concluded. Depending on the exact `SampleProcessor`, and the exact nature of the given `Sample`, the `Sample` may need to be multi-casted to a list of other recipient `SampleProcessors`.

This all feels like Camel to me.

So I ask:

- Does Akka have built-in support for routing, broadcasting, multi-casting and other EIPs (if so, what are they and where are they documented)?
- Or, should I try to integrate the actor system with Camel, in which case, what would that look like? I know there is a Camel-Akka component but I believe this is just for integrating a Camel bus with an actor system (whereas, I want a service bus *inside* my actor system)
- Or, should I just do my own homegrown EIP/actor wiring here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Akka obsolesce Camel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074223/does-akka-obsolesce-camel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka doesn't suport EIP natively, but there is several ways to implement it.

Anyway, if you want some handy DSL, there is a better idea than EIP - as it's done with [GoF-patterns](http://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/fp-patterns-ndc-london2014), you can replace (implement) most of EIP-patterns with functional composition + Functors (`map`) and Monads (`flatMap`). In other words, you can treat input stream as infinite collection. So,

- processors become functions
- pipes become functors, like `val output1 = input.map(processor1).map(processor2)`
- routers and filters become... monads (`filter` is based on `flatMap`):

  `val fork1 = output1.filter(routingCondition1).map(...)`

  `val fork2 = output1.filter(routingCondition2).map(...)`
- split is `flatMap`: `input.flatMap(x => Stream(x.submsg1, x.submsg2))`
- aggregators become catamorphisms, aka `fold` (accumulator should be usually backed by some storage)

Such stream-based workflow is already implemented for Akka and it's called [Akka Streams](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-stream-scala), which is an implementation of [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/), see also [this](http://akka.io/news/2014/09/12/akka-streams-0.7-released.html)
 and [that](http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2015/01/a-gentle-introduction-to-akka-streams/) articles.

Another option is to use Akka as is, actor guarantees sequential processing, so you can implement piping, by creating the chain of actors:

```
class Processor1(next: ActorRef) extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case x if filterCondition => 
      case x => next ! process(x)
   }
}

val processor2 = system.actorOf(Props[Processor2])
val processor1 = system.actorOf(Props[Processor1], processor2)
```

If you need routing - it's just two "next"'s

```
class Router(next1: ActorRef, next2: ActorRef) extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case x if filterCondition => 
      case x if cond1 => next1 ! process(x)
      case x if cond2 => next2 ! process(x)
   }
}
```

If you need to guarantee no races between routes - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28044978/1809978). Of cource, you loose the whole DSL idea, using actors directly.

P.S. Yes, you can still use Camel for endpoints - Akka have some [support](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html) for that. And you can use Akka as service-activator.